# Facebook's SetSize will work on Tab installs, but not regular viewings

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm having a serious issues with Facebook's FB.Canvas.setSize() functionality.

I've got some files with a large amount of data on them, so naturally, I thought to expand the size of the iFrame vertically.  Here's what I use:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
FB.init({
    appId  : '###',
    status : true,
    cookie : true // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
});
FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 2500 });
```

This work's great when displaying one of these files through a Tab installation on a fan page.  However, when looking at it by just going to the app, the resize doesn't happen.

Is there something I'm missing about Tab vs. Not Tab installs?

Other Details:
I have Auto-Resize set to true in the app settings, because that's how the boss wants it (no scrollbars). For grins I commented out setSize and manually added FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(false) in the code for these pages, and when not in a tab install, the scrollybars don't show up.  It's like when I'm not in a tab install the Javascript code isn't being activated.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!
Lisa

**Edit:** Finally finally finally got this to work.  @matt-nathanson set me on the right track, but the ultimate solution was a bit more in-depth than his suggestion.  Here's what I ended up doing:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId: '###', 
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        oauth: true
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

window.onload = function () {
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 2500 });
}
</script>
```

Solution from: http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-javascript-sdk-best-practices/58/

Answer (score 1):

give this a whirl....

first set

```
body {height: 2500px;}
```

then stick this in :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 520, height: 2500});
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 520, height: 2500});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @matt-nathanson , thanks for the help!  Unfortunately, that didn't seem to actually do anything.  I tried calling sizeChangeCallback() on load, as well as from an anchor tag "onClick".  :(  Here's my updated code: `window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId  : '###',
  status : true,
  cookie : true
 });
 FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 520, height: 2500});
}
function sizeChangeCallback() {
 FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 520, height: 2700});
}`